# How do I verify if a user has logon as a service right

Tags: windows, cmd

I tried looking up on google but most of the answers is how to provide the "logon as a service" rights to a user. 
Is there a command where i can find out given a user if that user has the logon as a service right?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
secedit /export /areas user_rights /cfg rights.txt
```

---

Source [Secedit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875548.aspx)